# Django formsets and files

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have this web app, created with Django framework and I'm struggling with one particular issue. I would like to create formset with file attachment (Attachment is related to Document vie FK relationship), and I would like to provide url to mentioned file in frontend.

**model.py**

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='name')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='attachments', null=True,
                            verbose_name='file')

class Document(models.Model):
    attachment = models.ForeignKey(
        'Attachment', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=False)

    def get_attachment_file(self):
        return self.attachment.file.url

    def get_attachment_filename(self):
        return str(self.attachment.file)[12:]
```

**form.py**

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Contract
    fields = ('attachment', 'date', 'title', 'approved')

DocumentFormset = modelformset_factory(Document, form=DocumentForm, extra=0)
```

**view.py**

```
def documents(request):

    ... some logic and filtering, get doc_id

    documents = Document.objects.filter(document=doc_id)
    formset = DocumentFormset(queryset=documents)

    return render(request, 'documents.html', {'formset': formset})
```

**template: documents.html**

```
{% for form in formset %}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.attachment.id_for_label }}">Title</label>
    {{ form.attachment}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I have hard time to access file url in attachment object, in template engine I cant call get_attachment_file() function, form.attachment.file.url is empty.

*Is there a way to get file url from attachment object?*

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `.name`? Like `{{ file.name }}` as specified here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.name. This should give you *"the name of the file including the relative path from MEDIA_ROOT."*

Comment: You are right, but it doesnt work in this case cause, file is at child object Aattachment) related to parent (Document), Document can only see model name of Attachment.

Comment: So, what you want here is to have multiple attachment for single document?